# ARKit: Multiple videos PLUS play/pause functionality that resumes the correct video

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit

Learning and LOVING ARKit, I'm going through an online class where the project is to create the Harry Potter-like newspaper that plays a video when the camera looks at an image on the paper. I'm taking the project a step further in trying to do two things:

1. Have the video pause when the camera moves off the image connected to the video and also
2. Play multiple video based off multiple images

I got the Play/Pause feature to work using this method():

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else {return}

    if imageAnchor.isTracked {
        videoNode.play()
    } else {
        videoNode.pause()
    }
}
```

And I got multiple videos to play using two global properties:

```
var movieName = "Friends.mp4"
var videoNode = SKVideoNode(fileNamed: "Friends.mp4")
```

And then within the ARSCNViewDeleegate method, I added the following code...

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
    let node = SCNNode()
    
    if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor {
        
        if imageAnchor.referenceImage.name == "HarryAndFriends" {
            movieName = "Friends.mp4"
        } else if imageAnchor.referenceImage.name == "Train" {
            movieName = "TrainStation.mp4"
        }
        
        videoNode = SKVideoNode(fileNamed: movieName)
        videoNode.play()
        
        let videoScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 1280, height: 720))
        videoNode.position = CGPoint(x: videoScene.size.width / 2, y: videoScene.size.height / 2)
        videoNode.yScale = -1.0
        videoScene.addChild(videoNode)
        
        let plane = SCNPlane(width: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)
        plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = videoScene
        
        let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
        planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
        
        node.addChildNode(planeNode)
    }
    
    return node
}
```

This mostly works!

I'm able to track Video1, move the camera off of Image1, and Video1 pauses. When I point the camera back on Image1, Video1 resumes. Perfect! Then moving to Image2, Video2 starts playing, as it should. I can move the camera off of Image2, and Video2 pauses, as it should.

However, when I position the camera back on Image1, Video1 appears, as and where it should, but Video2 resumes playing (I can hear the audio from Video2). Video1 does not play and is still paused where I left off.

Video2 is somehow stored in memory, and I can't figure out how to get it to swtich back.

I pulled info from these posts:

[Tracking multiple images and play their videos in ARkit2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52205105/tracking-multiple-images-and-play-their-videos-in-arkit2)

[Multiple image tracking ARKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73193461/multiple-image-tracking-arkit)

[ARKit How to Pause video when out of tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55281961/arkit-how-to-pause-video-when-out-of-tracking)

I just can't seem to combine the two concepts to resume the correct video. Any help?